# Ignore non-numeric elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
a = c(1, 3, 4, "hello", 4)
```

I want to create the sum of all the numeric elements, i.e. get "12". How can I do that?

Comment: `sum(as.numeric(c(1, 3, 4, "hello", 4)), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to `numeric`  and use `sum`.  The `as.numeric` part converts the non-numeric elements to `NA` which can be removed with `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
 sum(as.numeric(a), na.rm=TRUE)
```